# How to change IP pool for WiFi tethering on Nexus 5

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

I would like to know how to change IP pool of Wi-Fi spot mode on on Nexus 5. Could you tell me about it?

I just want control this pool if it's possible.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Is there a larger problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: It's not big issue. But, I just want to control my IP address pool.

Comment: Are you talking about your local WiFi network? If so, look into your router's DHCP settings.

Comment: No, Sorry I added it and It's on Nexus 5 for Wi-Fi spot mode to provide IP to such PC and other node.